# How do we create a document, give it some fields, and give it a sub collection all in a single call in firestore (RNFirestore)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

So, I have a collection in firestore and I add a document to it with some fields like follows:

```
const chatRef = firestore().collection('CHAT').doc(id);

    chatRef.set({
        field-1: 'something',
        field-2: 'something',
      })
      .then(() => { });
```

Now, to add a sub-collection to this document, I add the following code to "then". The complete code would look like:

```
    const chatRef = firestore().collection('CHAT').doc(id);

    chatRef.set({
        field-1: 'something',
        field-2: 'something',
      })
      .then(() => {
            chatRef.collection('MESSAGES').add(initialBotMessage)
              .then(() => { });
      });
```

I would like to do both this actions in a single call, but couldn't find any leads. Is there any way to do this? I was trying to improve performance with reducing the amount of promise calls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create multiple documents in a single API call. Writing to a single document always requires a single API call.

But you *can* have the two documents be created atomically, by using what Firestore calls a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). While this still requires one `set` call for each document, these will then be sent to the server (and committed or rejected there) as a single operation.